# Woocommerce products title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, title, alt

I would like to ask how to customize woo commerce products images.I want to add alt title featured products. Iv'e been tweaking on the functions.php . I saw woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail() how could I customize this to output the image title like this one:

```
<img src="www.source.com" title="image title">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);

if (!function_exists('change_product_image')) {
    function change_product_image( $html ){
        global $post;

        $html = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' );

        echo $html;
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'change_product_image', 10 );
```

First you remove the default action from woocommerce that displays the image, then you output yours with your function.

You can play around with this. Change size, find out attributes of each image etc.

Comment: everything was solved using 

get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full',get_the_title() );

Comment: You mean you used my code or some different? If my answer helped you feel free to mark it as correct (check mark below the score).